# Non-const lvalue reference to type - Error in Objective-C++ wrapper when using parameter of type Class

Tags: c++, objective-c, wrapper, objective-c++

I have two wrapper classes written in `Objective-C++` for their equivalent C++ classes. Let's call them `OABCClass` and `OXYZCallbackInterface`. Now I have a method in `C++ (ABCClass)` in which an argument is of a interface- `XYZCallbackInterface`.

For example :

```
std::string methodWithArguments(std::string req, CommonNamespace::XYZCallbackInterface &callback);
```

In my Objective-C++ wrapper class for i.e. `OABCClass` my method implementation for above mentioned C++ method looks like following:

```
-(NSString *)methodWithArguments(NSString*)req  callback(OXYZCallbackInterface*)callback {
    std::string res = cppClassVariable->methodWithArguments(req.UTF8String, callback);
}
```

Here I get error :

> Non-const lvalue reference to type 'Common::XYZCallbackInterface' cannot bind to a temporary of type 'Common::XYZCallbackInterface *'

**What is the correct way to use it? Any help is appreciated.**

```
  //Objective-C++ side
  #ifndef OXYZCallbackInterface_h
  #define OXYZCallbackInterface_h
  #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

  //.h
  @interface OXYZCallbackInterface : NSObject

  -(bool)onResponseAvailable:(NSString* )response;

  @end
  #endif /* OXYZCallbackInterface_h */

  //.mm
  #import "OXYZCallbackInterface.h"
  #include "Common/Common.Shared/OXYZCallbackInterface.h"

  using namespace CommonNamespace;

  @implementation OXYZCallbackInterface

  - (instancetype)init
  {
   self = [super init];
     return self;
  }

  -(bool)onResponseAvailable:(NSString* )response{
     bool isResp = _objIPICCallback->onResponseAvailable(response.UTF8String);
    return isResp;
 }

  @end

  //C++ side
  #pragma once

  #include "DataTypes.h"

 namespace CommonNamespace
 {
 class XYZCallbackInterface
 {
 public:
    virtual ~ XYZCallbackInterface() {}
    virtual bool onResponseAvailable(std::string response) = 0;
 };
}
```

And OABCClass.mm implementation looks like:

```
-(NSString*) methodWithArguments(NSString*)req  callback(OXYZCallbackInterface*)callback{
   NSString* result = @"";

   _pOABC -> methodWithArguments("", (__bridge XYZCallbackInterface*)callback);

   //  Error : Non-const lvalue reference to type CommonNamespace::XYZCallbackInterface cannot bind to a temporary of type CommonNamespace::XYZCallbackInterface *

   return result;
}
```

Comment: I know both C++ and objective C and this question is completely incomprehensible to me.  Are you trying to call into a C++ class from objective C (which is easy) or vice-versa?  If it's the latter, you need to 'wrap' the objective C object to provide a C++ API for it.

Comment: I am trying to call into a C++ class from objective C

Comment: Another way I have tried to cast cppClassVariable->methodWithArguments(req.UTF8String, (XYZCallbackInterface) callback);

Comment: Please add the declaration of the method you want to call to your question (NOT as a comment).  Then @ me.  Thanks.

Comment: Please check.@PaulSanders

Comment: OK, thanks.  What is `CommonNamespace::XYZCallbackInterface` for please?  Converting (say) an `NSString` into a `std::string` is straightforward enough but your second parameter is a foreign country to objective C.  Where do you think it is going to get one of those from?

Comment: What is the procedure to use Common::XYZCallbackInterface in a Wrapper Class?

Comment: This conversation has gone badly off the rails.  I'm out, sorry.

Comment: There seem to be colons missing in your method declarations. Is this something that just happened when SO formats your code, or are they actually not there? `-(NSString*) methodWithArguments(NSString*)req  callback(OXYZCallbackInterface*)callback` should really be `-(NSString*) methodWithArguments:(NSString*)req  callback:(OXYZCallbackInterface*)callback`

Answer (score 1):

You don't show your `OXYZCallbackInterface` Objective-C++ class, so it's hard to be sure how exactly it "wraps" the `XYZCallbackInterface` C++ interface. However, it's a sure thing that `OXYZCallbackInterface` is not a `XYZCallbackInterface` (in the object-oriented "is-a" sense). An instance of `OXYZCallbackInterface` is not an instance of `XYZCallbackInterface` (or any subclass). Therefore, you can't pass a pointer to an instance of `OXYZCallbackInterface` to a function expecting a reference to an instance of `XYZCallbackInterface`.

Your wrapper will have to provide a means to unwrap itself and return a pointer or reference to the original `XYZCallbackInterface` object that it wraps. Let's say it has this signature:

```
- (XYZCallbackInterface*) original;
```

Then, you could call the C++ method like so:

```
 std::string res = cppClassVariable->methodWithArguments(req.UTF8String, *[callback original]);
```

Comment: What about the implementation of `OXYZCallbackInterface`? In what way does it wrap `XYZCallbackInterface`?

Comment: Thank you for chipping in Ken.  You're making a much better fist of this than I did.

Comment: Added the implementation as well. Please check. @KenThomases

Comment: @icodes, from what you've posted, `OXYZCallbackInterface` is not in any way a wrapper for `XYZCallbackInterface`. A wrapper would imply that you have an instance of `XYZCallbackInterface` and you create an instance of `OXYZCallbackInterface` that holds that other object (in an instance variable, for example) and forwards messages that it receives to that object. You would only need to create such a wrapper if you needed to do things with it that you can't do with C++ objects, such as storing it in an `NSArray` or something. If you don't need that, just work with the C++ class itself.

Comment: @KenThomases: If you can share sample implementation, it would be really great.